# Kentico 12 Portal Engine - System error: An error occurred and your request couldn't be completed

Tags: kentico

When trying to open any page in the Pages application in the CMS, we got an error:
System error: An error occurred and your request couldn't be completed.
Click here to go back to the home page

There are no error logs in the Kentico event log application regarding this error.
In the windows Event viewer, the only thing related to this problem was a warning. The screen shot is attached.

After deploying the project files from one environment to another the error appeared. To be more precise, after replacing the old CMS folder with the new one.

We are using Kentico 12 Portal Engine

[System Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSAYD.png)

[Event Viewer details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfjHR.png)

Comment: are there any errors in the browser dev tool console? Any failed requests? If the same code works on one environment and not on another, what is the difference between them? I would try re-deploying. Make sure the target folder is cleared before deployment - so there are no old files messing up things. Then, the Event viewer error suggests, that there is some virtual app missing in the IIS - check this error on Google and make sure your IIS configuration is OK.

Comment: I solved the problem. There was a missing filed when creating a page type and that is the reason why the error was showing.